# How does LLVM emit AArch64's JumpTable?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, arm64

There are ARM32's JumpTable description in ArmAsmPrinter.cpp,
but there aren't any information of AArch64's JumpTable in AArch64AsmPrinter.cpp

But,
Compiler can emit JumpTable to Binaries.

So, how does LLVM do it?